# Jtextarea won't come out

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

i have a bit of problem, the function of my program is to display the selected items
     i have clicked on the JList area and after clicking on the OK button, a receipt will come out from the 
     JtextArea with the total, tax and items, i've been trying it out but the receipt w/ total, tax and items (JTextArea) won't
     come out.

Comment: Nobody understands what you need.

Comment: I'm afraid it's very difficult to understand your question.  Do you have some code that's not working?  If so, share it with us and we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 4):

> JList area and after clicking on the OK button, a receipt will come out from the JtextArea with the total, tax and items, i've been trying it out but the receipt w/ total, tax and items (JTextArea) won't come out.

1. question in this form isn't answerable, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)
2. maybe [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) isn't proper JComponent for showing `a receipt will come out from the JtextArea with the total, tax and items`, better could be to use another [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) (or [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)) for display `total, tax and items`
3. is there are only a few field for calculating or dispalying the `total, tax and items` the to use [JFormattedTextFiedls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) with `Number Formatter` to avoiding any parsing String to number or vice versa

Answer (score 3):

check the following sample code for JList:

```
 public class PhilosophersJList extends JFrame {

 private DefaultListModel philosophers;
 private JList list;

 public PhilosophersJList()
     {
     super( "Favorite Philosophers" );

     // create a DefaultListModel to store philosophers
     philosophers = new DefaultListModel();
     philosophers.addElement( "Socrates" );
     philosophers.addElement( "Plato" );
     philosophers.addElement( "Aristotle" );
     philosophers.addElement( "St. Thomas Aquinas" );
     philosophers.addElement( "Soren Kierkegaard" );
     philosophers.addElement( "Immanuel Kant" );
     philosophers.addElement( "Friedrich Nietzsche" );
     philosophers.addElement( "Hannah Arendt" );

     // create a JList for philosophers DefaultListModel
     list = new JList( philosophers );

     // allow user to select only one philosopher at a time
     list.setSelectionMode(
     ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION );

     // create JButton for adding philosophers
     JButton addButton = new JButton( "Add Philosopher" );
     addButton.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {

         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
             {
             // prompt user for new philosopher's name
             String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
             PhilosophersJList.this, "Enter Name" );

             // add new philosopher to model
             philosophers.addElement( name );
         }
     }
     );

     // create JButton for removing selected philosopher
     JButton removeButton =
     new JButton( "Show Details" );

     removeButton.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {

         public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
             {
              String details = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(PhilosophersJList.this, "Tax :", list.getSelectedValue());
        philosophers.addElement(details);

         }
     }
     );

     // lay out GUI components
     JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel();
     inputPanel.add( addButton );
     inputPanel.add( removeButton );

     Container container = getContentPane();
     container.add( list, BorderLayout.CENTER );
     container.add( inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH );

     setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     setSize( 400, 300 );
     setVisible( true );

 } // end PhilosophersJList constructor

 // execute application
 public static void main( String args[] )
     {
     new PhilosophersJList();
 }
}
```